# How do I install solc on Mac Osx? Error encountered "Error: No formulae found in taps."

Tags: mac-osx, solc

I'm trying to install a solidity compiler on my Mac. 
I've followed the guide here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contract-Tutorial

The error that I've gotten when installing ccp-ethereum is "Error: No formulae found in taps."

```
zhongqin-imac:~ ngzhongqin$ brew install cpp-ethereum
Error: No available formula with the name "cpp-ethereum" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [Solidity - Binary Packages](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/installing-solidity.html#binary-packages):

> ```
> brew update
> brew upgrade
> brew tap ethereum/ethereum
> brew install solidity
> ```

Comment: This worked great.  Minor comment, on the last line I got *Warning: `brew linkapps` has been deprecated and will eventually be removed!* -- but it worked fine for me without this.

Comment: If you need a specific version, then you'll need to find the specific commit corresponding to your version of this file: https://github.com/ethereum/homebrew-ethereum/commits/master/solidity.rb
then get the raw URL, and run 
`brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/homebrew-ethereum/de1da16f7972a899fc8dd1f3f04299eced6f4312/solidity.rb`

Comment: brew  linkapps is deprecated

Comment: @Rexcirus Removed `brew linkapps`