# Stuck on Install Solidity with Brew on MacOSX

Tags: solidity, mac-osx, brew

I tried to install Solidity [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9513/how-do-i-install-solc-on-mac-osx-error-encountered-error-no-formulae-found-in/9514) way, but as soon as I do `brew install solidity` it stops at the following line:

`==> ./b2 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.1 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boos`

Does anybody know why it stops at this point?

Many thanks in advance!

#### UPDATE:

You just have to wait! It may take a little longer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same trouble and found the following url:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744697/i-cannot-get-solidity-installed-with-homebrew-on-macos-sierra-installation-hang

and patience solved.

Comment: Please include a summary or some details instead of just a link.

Comment: Summary of this is: just wait a little bit longer... :-) took about 20 min